# How to "jitter" a vector of numbers?

Tags: r, vector

The concept of jittering in graphical plotting is intended to make sure points do not overlap. I want to do something similar in a vector

Imagine I have a vector like this:

```
v <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.55, 0.60, 0.71, 0.71, 0.8)
```

As you can see, it is a vector that is ordered by increasing numbers, with the caveat that some of the numbers are exactly the same. How can I "jitter" them through adding a very small value, so that they can be ordered strictly in increasing order? I would like to achieve something like this:

```
0.5, 0.50001, 0.55, 0.60, 0.71, 0.71001, 0.8
```

How can I achieve this in R?

If the solution allows me to adjust the size of the "added value" it's a bonus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jitter and then sort:

```
sort(jitter(z))
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `rle` gets you the run length of repeated elements in a vector. Using this information, you can then create a `sequence` of the repeats, multiply this by your `verySmallNumber` and add it to `v`.

```
# New vector to illustrate a triplet
v <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.55, 0.60, 0.71, 0.71, 0.71, 0.8)

# Define the amount you wish to add
verySmallNumber <- 0.00001

# Get the rle
rv <- rle(v)

# Create the sequence, multiply and subtract the verySmallNumber, then add
sequence(rv$lengths) * verySmallNumber - verySmallNumber + v
# [1] 0.50000 0.50001 0.55000 0.60000 0.71000 0.71001 0.71002 0.80000
```

Of course, eventually, a very long sequence of repeats might lead to a value equal to the next real value. Adding a check to see what the longest repeated value is would possibly solve that.

Comment: or `v + (ave(v, v, FUN = seq_along) - 1 ) * .00001`

Comment: I smell a microbenchmarking task. What will I do with the extra 12 microseconds?

Comment: you could type `verySmallNumber ` a couple more times

Comment: or call it `verySmallNumberThatMightRunOver`